# generating sound waves according to sound intensity through javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

i am trying to integrate jquery based audio player/recorder with sound waves. we've got the idea of generating sound waves from there -: http://js.do/sound-waves-with-javascript/
i want to generate the same waves according to the sound depth(intensity) as music playing. is it possible to do it? i really need help to get it done.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It's one thing to generate a sound based on some math, and then create a visual representation of that sound with javascript based on the same math.

The HTML5 audio element does not however have access to any information from the sound file to generate any visual representation of the sound playing, other than the rather new and experimental [HTML5 Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API), which has limited browser support, but will work in some newer browsers.

Another option would be to run the audio file in a Python script or something similar to generate a text file with amplitudes in intervals that can be used to generate visual representations of the sound, but the only implementations of this that I've seen are instances where just one audio file is implemented for demo purposes etc. and setting something up to work with Python serverside for any audio file would probably be rather complicated. There's more on how to use Python to genereate sound data [here](http://ricardocabello.com/blog/post/677)!

Lastly, there's always flash ?